# Error in R.java due to an XML file

Tags: android, xml

So I created this new layout in another project and it somehow corrupted it (the project). R.java shows an error on a line

```
    public static final class id 
   {
       **public static final int 0dp=0x7f06003b;**
       public static final int AutoCompleteTextView01=0x7f060031;
```

The line with the asterisks gives an error:

**Syntax error on token "0d", delete this token**

I thought it was just a fluke so I copied my layout xml to a working project and put it there. Bam. Same error generated in that project. I want to know if there is a problem with my layout XML.

The variable names are all generic because this was just a demo design. **Can the problem be caused by the 0.5dp values I'm using?**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#FBF2EF"
    android:fillViewport="true" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="15dp"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:paddingRight="15dp"
        android:paddingTop="15dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/RadioGroup01"
            android:text="Pickup Address or Postcode"
            android:textSize="11sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/line1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_marginTop="0.5dp"
            android:background="#000000" />

        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/radioGroup"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/line1"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/line1"
            android:layout_below="@+id/line1"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:checked="true"
                android:text="Address"
                android:textSize="10sp" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:checked="false"
                android:text="Postcode"
                android:textSize="10sp" />
        </RadioGroup>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/radioGroup"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/radioGroup"
            android:layout_below="@+id/radioGroup"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:weightSum="4.0" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.8"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:text="House"
                android:textSize="10sp" >

                <requestFocus />
            </EditText>

            <AutoCompleteTextView
                android:id="@+id/EditText01"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="2.5"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="textPostalAddress"
                android:text="Street Address"
                android:textSize="10sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/Button01"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.7"
                android:background="@drawable/roundedbutton"
                android:text="Locate"
                android:textSize="10sp" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/linearLayout1"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/linearLayout1"
            android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout1"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:weightSum="4.0" >

            <AutoCompleteTextView
                android:id="@+id/AutoCompleteTextView01"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="3.3"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="textCapCharacters"
                android:text="Enter Postcode"
                android:textSize="10sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.7"
                android:background="@drawable/roundedbutton"
                android:text="Search"
                android:textSize="10sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/View01"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/TextView01"
            android:layout_below="@+id/TextView01"
            android:layout_marginTop="0.5dp"
            android:background="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextView01"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/LinearLayout01"
            android:layout_below="@+id/LinearLayout01"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="Destination Address"
            android:textSize="11sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/View01"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/View01"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Destination Address"
            android:inputType="textPostalAddress"
            android:textSize="10sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextView02"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText2"
            android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="Car Type, Passengers and Payment"
            android:textSize="11sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/TextView02"
            android:layout_below="@+id/TextView02"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:weightSum="3" >

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinner2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinner1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinner3"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/View02"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/TextView02"
            android:layout_below="@+id/TextView02"
            android:layout_marginTop="0.5dp"
            android:background="#000000" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/linearLayout2"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/linearLayout2"
            android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout2"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:weightSum="2" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/0dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="A/C Number"
                android:textSize="10sp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="Password"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textSize="10sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_width="70dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="41dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/TextView01"
                android:background="@drawable/roundedbutton"
                android:text="Continue"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/TextView03"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="When"
                android:textSize="11sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/View03"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/TextView03"
                android:layout_below="@+id/TextView03"
                android:layout_marginTop="0.5dp"
                android:background="#000000" />

            <RadioGroup
                android:id="@+id/RadioGroup01"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/View03"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/View03"
                android:layout_below="@+id/View03"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp" >

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/RadioButton02"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:checked="true"
                    android:text="Now"
                    android:textSize="10sp" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/RadioButton01"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:checked="false"
                    android:text="Later"
                    android:textSize="10sp" />
            </RadioGroup>

    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem is with this

```
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/0dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="A/C Number"
            android:textSize="10sp" />
```

Do this

```
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/EditText0dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="A/C Number"
            android:textSize="10sp" />
```

#### Always follow naming conventions **Never start any id with Numbers**

After changing this You can Clean and Rebuild the project

[image]

Comment: hmmm its ok some times it happens so next time be sure there is some new error

Answer (score 1):

id cannot start with a digit or a symbol except _